# Error: misuse of undefined type 'struct IntArray'

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc, modularization

I want to write this program where I have this in one file named `intarray.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "intarray.h"

struct IntArray
{
    int length;
    int *array;
};

struct IntArray erzeugeArr(int length)
{
    struct IntArray erzeugt = {length, (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*length)};
    return erzeugt;
}
```

and this in the test main:

```
struct IntArray *string;
string = &(erzeugeArr(5));
```

Now, what I get is this:

> Misuse of undefined type "struct IntArray"

because of the last bit with `string = …`. I have searched a lot, but I don’t understand the problem! If I do it like this:

```
void erzeugeArr(struct IntArray *erzeuge, int length)
{
    struct IntArray erzeugt = {length, (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*length)};
    erzeuge = &erzeugt;
}
```

and

```
struct IntArray *string;
erzeugeArr(string, 5);
```

, then I can compile my program, but when starting it, I get a segmentation fault, which I assume I get because the main has no access to `erzeugt`?

Comment: Please provide a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/). From what I see, the reason can be a trivial as forgetting to include a header. But that's hard to tell when I don't see what you actually try to compile.

Comment: Why did not you use a normal array than a struck array?

Comment: In both cases you are returning local variable from function. Time to read about *variable scope* in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are returning the address of a local (struct) variable, which, when you try to use it later, will give you a segmentation fault (trying to access an invalid address).

You can dynamically allocate a structure in function and return it.

```
        struct IntArray* erzeugeArr(int length)
        {
            struct IntArray *erzeugt=(struct IntArray*)malloc(sizeof(struct IntArray*));
            erzeugt->array = (int*) malloc(sizeof (int)*length);
            return erzeugt;
        }

        int main()
        {
            struct IntArray *str;
            str=erzeugeArr(10);
            //use str for processing
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works! Don't know why I didn't try it this way ^^ Nevertheless I have still this problem with when I want to access the length of the structure str is pointing at in the main. I tried str->length, and get the error "dereferencing of pointer to incomplete type". Like wildplasser said below, an expression of type struct IntArray has no address, so I guess I get why it doesn't work this way, but I don't know, how I can do it otherwise...

Comment: you want to do it other way?

Comment: You mean length for total elements? why don't you use simply int*arr or arr[]? if its char* might say acts like string. whats your purpose?

Comment: It has to be a structure composed of the array and its length. That's the assignment. To test the functionality in the main I want to access the length in the structure.

Comment: can't you use array simply and use sizeof to find length?

Comment: I guess, but the assignment says it has to be a structure.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution on my own. Again, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `string = &(erzeugeArr(5));` statement attempts to take the address of an expression (the function returns an expression of type `struct IntArray`.) Only objects have addresses, expressions dont.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
struct IntArray
{
  int length;
  int *array;
}

struct IntArray *alloc_arr(int length)
{
  struct IntArray *erzeugt = calloc(sizeof(struct IntArray));
  erzeugt->length = length;
  erzeugt->array = calloc(length * sizeof(int));
  return erzeugt;
}

void free_arr(struct IntArray *p)
{
  free(p->array);
  free(p);
}
```

Alternatively, you could also do something a little sneakier which allocates the struct at a size big enough to contain the array of ints inline:

```
struct IntArray
{
  int length;
  int array[1];
}

struct IntArray *alloc_arr(int length)
{
  struct IntArray *erzeugt = calloc(sizeof(struct IntArray) + (length-1) * sizeof(int));
  erzeugt->length = length;
  return erzeugt;
}

void free_arr(struct IntArray *p)
{
  free(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

&(erzeugeArr(5)) is awkward. It seems to return an address of the function. But C compiler would fail due to lvalue required error.

Instead try the following:-

```
struct IntArray *string,s1;

s1=erzeugeArr(5);
string = (struct IntArray *) &s1;  // If you really require pointer access
```